# swap(int *,int *) showing different behavior when calling with and without "&"operator

Tags: c++, pointers

i am using following code in selection sort program for swap the value.When i pass arguments like  **swap(a[min],a[j])** It swaps the values but doesn't increment the **"swaps"** variable.
But when i pass arguments like **swap(&a[min],&a[j])** It swaps the value as well as increment the **"swaps"** variable. I didn't get what is happening under the hood.
I am using minGW compiler.

```
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
swaps++;
int temp;
temp=*x;
*x=*y;
*y=temp;

}
```

Comment: You have a `using namespace std;`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, actually i was not aware that namespace has it's own swap .Thank you

Comment: that's [why “using namespace std;” is considered a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 6):

When you use `swap(a[min],a[j])`, you are most likely calling `std::swap`. Another reason to avoid

```
using namespace std;
```